# Set up email with DirectAdmin Panel not working

Tags: html, html-email, directadmin

I have a `directAdmin` panel to host my HTML website. I created a new email by going to `"Email manager" -> "Email accounts"` and `"Create Account"`. Once account is created, I tried sending email from a different account to this new email. It says

> Your message wasn't delivered to **********.com because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail.

I'm not sure how to set up a working email account through DirectAdmin. Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

for problems in receiving an email in directadmin :

- first check that your domain has a valid mx record in dns zone . like mx : mail.domain.com with high priority for example 10
- ping your mx address in windows CMD for example : ping  mail.domain.com and it should return the ip of hosted server . ip should be same as the result of ping domain.com
- if above steps didnt work . you should check the owner and permission of files in this path : /etc/virtual/domain.com . the ownership should be mail:mail
- check the status of exim service . for example in redhat OS distributions check the command : service exim status . it should be running and active without error